# How to convert a flat array of objects into a nested JSON data in JavaScript/React using split() method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nested, treeview

I have a flat array of objects which is quite complex and there are no ids in the objects. I have to convert this flat array into nested JSON data by splitting the second element's value and each value will be children of the previous children.[array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcMna.jpg) The third/last level which is 2301,2302 etc will have the asset value as its child. [nested json hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBLAB.jpg)Any idea how to achieve this? I am fairly new to React. My ultimate goal is to create a sidebar like this[treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPj1y.jpg) to my React component. Please help!

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *splitting the second element's value and each value will be children*?

Comment: please add the Expected Json structure in the question. So people know exactly how you want your resulting Json.

Comment: i have the added the input and the output and the expected application, all 3 images. please check!

Comment: 5928 will have a child which is LBV and LBV will have a child which is 2301 and 2301 will have a value of the asset element of the object as its child.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.